# How do I check which #define was compiled into binary?

Tags: c++, linux

for some reason the wrong opensslv.h header is being included via cmake, or so I think. I would like to be sure and print out which value for "OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER" was compiled into my binary. 
How do I do that?

Comment: `std::cout << OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER << '\n';`?

Comment: @Galik is there any specific reason you're mixing C and C++? Why not use `std::endl`? If you want to use `\n` it should just be a `printf`, if you're going to use `std::cout` then that should be the standard held for all statements and should continue to use the standard library.

Comment: Galik, it's a library

Comment: @Ingenioushax: What are you talking about? `'\n'` is a perfectly valid C++ character literal.

Comment: @Ingenioushax `\n` adds a newline. `std::endl` adds a newline *and* flushes the stream. Two different things. `\n` is perfectly fine (and preferable) when you just want the newline and not the flush.

Comment: @Ingenioushax Using `'\n'` is not "mixing C and C++" - ending a line with `'\n'` is perfectly valid C++. The only real difference between the two is that `std::endl` [also flushes the buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/213977/1600898).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I know it's _valid_ C++. So is `int *myInt = (int*)malloc(500 * sizeof(int));`. Is it valid? Yes. Does it work? Sure. Is it conforming to the standards? No. While `\n` is a perfectly valid escape sequence, _I_ wouldn't put it as the preferred method for a line ending in C++.

Comment: @Ingenioushax: But *why* wouldn't you? And what's it have to do with "mixing C and C++"?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, **A**) I think it's laziness unless embeeded in a string (errr). The following is perfectly fine in my book, but still falls in the lazy category `cout << "This is a string\n";`. **B**) It's much harder to find '`\n`' than it is `<< endl` if you need to hunt a bug or implement a feature change. **C**) A decent number of developers don't _know_ that there is a STDOUT and STDIN buffer.

Comment: @Ingenioushax We'll have to agree to differ. I would say that ending a line with `\n` should be the recommended method over `std::endl` which can be less efficient. Also its easier for maintenance if its sent as a separate character and not embedded in the string literal.

Comment: @Galik: I can see that point, and I don't necessarily disagree with the statement. I suppose that's why coding standards for grander issues are for the greater good of humanity. :D

Comment: @Blub oopsie, of course. You could try `$ strings /path/to/library.so`

Comment: @Ingenioushax Both `\n` and `std::endl` are entirely valid ways of sending a newline in C++, and each has its uses.  If you're only outputting a single line, go with `endl` to flush the buffer afterwards.  If you're outputting multiple lines, use `\n` between each line, and `endl` after the final line.  You'll generally get more efficient results that way.  The main benefit of `endl`, after all, is that it both sends `\n` and flushes the buffer for you at the same time, so you don't have to do both operations separately.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by @Galik mentions, you can print out the value of the macro if you can edit the source.

If all you have is a binary then it gets hard, since the preprocessor will have replaced the macro name with its value before the compiler ever sees the source. So the binary does not contain any "link" back to the original macro name.

Some compilers (in my experience clang does it best) *can* embed such information in the binary when building with debug symbols enabled so it can print better error messages and make debugging more effective. 
But in an optimized binary without debug symbols you are close to being out of luck. That is, unless you start digging through a disassembly of the binary around where you know the macro is used and you know potential values it might take. Then you *might* be able to dig it out.